# Linkedin Share API 403 Access Denied

Tags: php, api, linkedin-api, postman

While trying to use LinkedIn share API, I have successfully created an application and given all permissions to that application, e.g., `r_basicprofile`, `r_emailaddress`, `rw_company_admin`, `w_share`.

My body content is as follows -

```
{
"content": {
           "title": "The title",
           "description": "the description",
           "submittedUrl": "GAVE_MY_URL",
           "submittedImageUrl": "GAVE_My_IMAGE_URL"
           },
           "comment": "demo comment",
           "visibility": {
                         "code": "anyone"
                         }
}
```

My header was -

```
Content-Type: application/json 
x-li-format: json 
Authorization: Bearer GAVE_MY_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Every time I do a request, I get the following response -

```
{ 
    "errorCode": 0, 
    "message": "Access to posting shares denied",         
    "requestId": "GZTBG1IZ2L", 
    "status": 403, 
    "timestamp": 1478159135348 
}
```

N.B.: I have tried POSTMAN and PHP cURL.

Could anyone please help me....Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/".$company_id."/shares?format=json&oauth2_access_token=".GAVE_MY_ACCESS_TOKEN

without Authorization in your header.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me too, and after exploring many things and spending many hours, I fixed this, actually I was not including the port number into to "Redirect URLs".

[image]